# Automation Error -2147221080 (800401a8)

Tags: excel, vba

Im intending to conduct a VBA macro which returns the cell value of C34 of the file referenced by path which has the sheet names as presented in myHeadings.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim myHeadings() As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim path As String
  path = "C:\pathtofile\file.xlsx"
  Dim currentWb As Workbook
  Set currentWb = ActiveWorkbook
  Dim openWb As Workbook
  Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
  Dim openWs As Worksheet

  myHeadings = Split("Januari,Februari,Mars", ",")

  For i = 0 To UBound(myHeadings)
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets(myHeadings(i))

    currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("AA" & 73+Application.Match   (myHeadings(i),Array,False)).Value = openWs.Range("C34").Value

  Next i
End Sub
```

This however gives the error message: Automation Error -2147221080 (800401a8) at the code snippet:

```
 currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("AA73+Application.Match   (i,Array,False)").Value = openWs.Range("C34").Value
```

I'm new to VBA and am yet to create a macro actually runable, so the cause may be trivial. From googling I'm yet to find a solution to this specific problematic.

EDITED some code to remove "Array" and updated t

Comment: Are you using `Currentwb` to refer to the workbook from which you are running the macro or the workbook that got opened? I reckon `currentWb` is referring to `file.xlsx` and not the macro workbook if I understood what you're trying to achieve correctly?

Comment: This is incorrect ``"Range(AA73+Application.Match   (i,Array,False)"`` - you probably mean  `Range("AA73")+Application.Match   (i,Array,False)`

Comment: @JLILIAmen Thanks for your reply! I'm having a workbook open, and I use Alt + F11 to launch the macro from there. I have the module in the Project with the same name as "currentWb". Can this be true? Where do you gather that currentWb is referring to file.xlsx?

Comment: @brettdj Thanks for reply! I've adjusted so that it says: currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("AA73"+Application.Match(i,Array,False)) = openWs.Range("C34") which negates the "Automation error", but presents me with Syntax error. Can you see where this error arises from?

Comment: What is `Array` in `Application.Match(i, Array, False)`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: @Aiken This is a spin-off from a code I found some Days ago. Actually, I didn't reflect of Array needing a definition. As the original code did not have any user-made function or anything called Array, I simply thought Array were a built in way of Writing Arrays.

Comment: Edited OP to account for Array

Comment: I wasn't referring to the `Array("Januari", "Februari", "Mars")` statement but rather to the use of the word `Array` within your `Application.Match()` function call. Your use of it to assign an array was perfectly correct.

Comment: @Aiken Thanks alot! That solved the problem! For each loop I wanted to get the index of the corresponding element from the myHeading Array. So naturally, I should check for myHeadings(i) in the Array myHeadings, not in a function called Array. 

As such: currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("AA" & 73+Application.Match   (myHeadings(i),myHeadings,False)).Value = openWs.Range("C34").Value

Is the way to go.. Thanks again!

Comment: ... Isn't `i` the index of the corresponding element? Why bother going through the hassle of `Application.Match()` to find out something you already know? You're literally saying "I want to find the index of the item with index i"

Comment: Aiken is right, but where i (the index number) is 0, the match function would return 1 (the position). What you are trying to do is equivalent to currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("AA" & 73+ i + 1).Value = openWs.Range("C34").Value, I've re-edited my answer below

Comment: @Aiken Hmm.. that's true. Didn't think of it being that simple, really. By analog, to copy the values from A280 to, say C280 it would be something in the lines of: currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Cells(280, i + 1) = openWs.Range("C34")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("AA" & 73 + Application.Match(i,Array,False)) = openWs.Range("C34")
```

If the result of

```
Application.Match(i,Array,False)
```

is equal to 1, you want to make AA74 to equal whatever is in openws.Range("C34"), right?

'&' is a concatentation character, so what we are saying above is that we take "AA" then calculate 73 + 1 and concatenate it to the end. The bit you were missing is escaping the text after the "AA" to do the numerical calculation.

**EDIT:-**

After reading Aiken's comments above, I believe your answer should be to remove the Match function entirely:

```
currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("AA" & 73 + i + 1).Value = openWs.Range("C34").Value
```

Comment: Yes that is what I meant to do! This gives me syntax error once again though, even if I copy paste your snippet of code.

Comment: Please see edited part of my answer, if this does the job I will edit it into a one-part answer

Comment: Thanks for explanation. This still gives syntax error in the same line.